# Compression for custom mime type works on IIS 7.5, but not IIS 7.0?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I've managed to set up compression for a custom mime type on IIS 7.5 with no problem. Add the mime type to IIS then add it to the httpCompression element in applicationHost.config. But when I do the same thing on IIS 7, the particular mime type is never compressed. This isn't a problem with compression in general since other mime types are compressed correctly. As far as I can tell, IIS 7 and IIS7.5 are configured in exactly the same way. Does IIS7 behave differently and do I need to do something else to get it working?

I've setup failed request tracing and get a NO_MATCHING_CONTENT_TYPE error during compression but I can't figure out what else I need to do to tell IIS about my mime type

Comment: Post the relevant portions of `applicationHost.config`. What specific MIME Type doesn't compress?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion! Either use an XML-capable comparison tool like BeyondCompare, or like [Web Deployment Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569005%28WS.10%29.aspx) (-verb:sync -whatif) to compare configurations, particularly at the applicationhost.config level.

Comment: Thanks, there are some differences between the applicationHost.config files but nothing that looks like it would explain the difference

Comment: It'd help to have comparative FREB logs. Otherwise - does the Windows level know about the file type on one, and not the other? (is the Mime type registered in the registry on one of the boxes?)